# How to connect to the kubernetes pod from the remote machine?

Tags: go, kubernetes, grpc

I have Kubernetes cluster in DigitalOcean and there is a pod with gRPC server inside. I have gGRP client on my local machine. My client is written in go.

**The goal is to connect gRPC client from my local machine to gRPC server inside DO k8s cluster.**

I read this guide: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-services/
and tried to connect with this type of uri: `http://kubernetes_master_address/api/v1/namespaces/namespace_name/services/[https:]service_name[:port_name]/proxy`

Here is a part of my client code:

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial(addr, grpc.WithInsecure())
if err != nil {
    glog.Fatalln("grpc.Dial()", err.Error())
}
```

But I got always get an error like this: `transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: address ...`

Comment: Please describe your setup, you have a service for your gRPC? Can you please share your deployment or pod and your service manifest?

Answer (score 0):

It’s probably better to first test if the port is reachable from the outside, e.g. by doing `telnet <uri> <port>`.
When you can connect to the host and port you can look further at whether you can connect via the grpc client.